# Angular prepopulate an array only once

Tags: angularjs

In angular I want to pre populate the todos array only once when the page loads and push this array into localStorage
where it can then be modified by add and splice functions cleanly even if the app has page refreshes

controller code

```
       $scope.initializeGame = function () {


            $scope.todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) || [];

              */ This is what I'm using to prepopulate the array but I only want it to do it once
               and page refreshes creates new items                 

               for(var i = 0 ; i < parseInt(2) ; i++)
                $scope.todos.push({id:i, Index: i, Answered: 'No', Correct:'?'});


               $scope.addTodo = function (){
                $scope.todos.push({id:i, Index: i, Answered: 'Yes', Correct: '?'})
                    $scope.newTodo = ''
                }

                $scope.spliceTodo = function (){
                $scope.todos.splice(1, 1, {id:i, Index: i, Answered: 'Yes', Correct: 'Correct'})
                $scope.replaceTodo = ''
                }



                $scope.clearCompleted =function() {
                    $scope.todos = $scope.todos.filter(function(item){
                        return !item.done


                    })
                }



                   $scope.$watch('todos',function(newValue, oldValue){
                    if(newValue!=oldValue){
                            localStorage.setItem('todos',JSON.stringify(newValue))
                    }
                }, true)
```

}

HTML

```
                          <div >
                            <form name="frm" ng-submit="addTodo()">
                                <input type="text" name="newtodo" ng-model="newTodo" required />
                                <button >Add </button>
                            </form>
                            <form name="frm" ng-submit="spliceTodo()">
                            <input type="text" name="replaceTodo" ng-model="replaceTodo" required />
                            <button >Splice </button>
                            </form></div>
```

Comment: If you're saving to localStorage, can't you check if the array already exists before populating it? Or at least, save a boolean somewhere that tells you the array is already populated as soon as you refresh the page.

Comment: if ($scope.todos.length !=0) {


                    for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(2); i++)
                        $scope.todos.push({id: i, Index: i, Answered: 'No', Correct: '?'});

                }

Comment: Try that and see if it works. If it does, perfect!